# ERROR: referenced relation "table name" is not a table

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE slack_commands_log (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "userId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  command VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL, 
  time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users (id));
```

result:

> ERROR:  referenced relation "users" is not a table

users is in public schema

Comment: Is users a table or something else, like a view?

Comment: it is a table .

Answer (score -2):

Thanks.
I figure it out, the users table is a foreign table.

Comment: and what did you do?